# Cheat Sheet of UNIX commands for Data Science

Tags: tools, beginner, processing

I was looking for a cheat sheet of UNIX commands, which are specifically usable for data science. I mean an introduction to very basic commands (starting from `cd`, `ls`, `pwd`, to some still simple but usable for data - e.g. `wc`, a few simple things with pipes, `ssh`, maybe `s3cmd`, etc), with some minimalistic examples.

I couldn't find one; or at least, nothing close to:

- [Git Cheat Sheet](http://byte.kde.org/~zrusin/git/git-cheat-sheet-medium.png)
- [Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)
- [series of R Cheat Sheets](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/)

I am pretty much aware of [datascienceatthecommandline.com](http://datascienceatthecommandline.com/), but my goal would be to have a 1-2 A4 pages printout, with really simple stuff.

If there is one (but I missed it), I would be grateful for posting it as an answer. If there isn't, then I am asking to post pieces of such list.

(If Moderator permits, we may create one list with Community Wiki.)

EDIT: The closest thing I've found is here: [Useful Unix commands for data science](http://www.gregreda.com/2013/07/15/unix-commands-for-data-science/) (very nice, but missing the very introductory part).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend this one - http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/ubunturef.pdf

Its comprehensive, but not data science specific.

There are a number of great cheat sheets here that may be what you are looking for:https://dzone.com/refcardz

If you are wanting to create your own, this is a very nice tool: http://www.cheatography.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is a post that starts from data science and walks you through options for completing common tasks:  http://www.drbunsen.org/explorations-in-unix/.